# C++ and cython - Seeking a design pattern that avoids template limitations

Tags: python, c++, templates, design-patterns, cython

One of the major issues in Cython is the lack of template support from within python files. I have a simulation system written in C++, and I wrap the various classes with Cython and run them using python.

When a c++ method is templated, one can't send the template class to the wrapper method from within python - instead, I end up sending strings to Cython, which then has to check the string against known values, manually passing the C++ class to the underlying C++ method. This makes absolute sense, as Cython does need to know the possible template arguments in order to compile the C++, but it is an issue nonetheless.

This is becoming a real annoyance as the list of candidates for these templated methods is growing - especially in the case of two or three templates to the one c++ method, where I have to do two or three layers of if statements within cython.

Fortunately, I'm in the lucky position of being the only writer and user of this codebase at the moment. I am very happy to refactor, and want to take the opportunity to do so to save headaches in the future. I'm in particular looking for advice as to some of the ways I can avoid the use of templating on the C++ side (as a design pattern problem), rather than relying on some kind of hacky approach on the cython side. If cython has these limitations on templates.

I have written up a minimal working example to highlight the kind of process that occurs in my program. In reality, though, it's a condensed matter simulation which benefits greatly from parallel processing (using OMP), and this is where my templating seems, to me, necessary. Whilst trying to keep it minimal as in simplicity, it compiles and produces output so that you can see what's going on. It's compiled with g++, and I link against OMP using -lgomp (or remove the pragmas and include) and use the std=c++11 flag.

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <omp.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

/*
 * Just a class containing some components to run through
 * a Modifier (see below)
 */
class ToModify{
public:
    std::vector<double> Components;
    ToModify(std::vector<double> components) : Components(components){}
};

/*
 * An abstract class which handles the modification of ToModify
 * components in an arbitrary way.
 * It is, however, known that child classes have a parameter
 * (here, unimaginatively called Parameter).
 * These parameters have a minimum and maximum value, which is
 * to be determined by the child class.
 */
class Modifier{
protected:
    double Parameter;
public:
    Modifier(double parameter = 0) : Parameter(parameter){}
    void setParameter(double parameter){
        Parameter = parameter;
    }
    double getParameter(){
        return Parameter;
    }
    virtual double getResult(double component) = 0;
};

/*
 * Compute component ratios with a pre-factor.
 * The minimum is zero, such that getResult(component) == 0 for all components.
 * The maximum is such that getResult(component) <= 1 for all components.
 */
class RatioModifier : public Modifier{
public:
    RatioModifier(double parameter = 0) : Modifier(parameter){}
    double getResult(double component){
        return Parameter * component;
    }

    static double getMaxParameter(const ToModify toModify){
        double maxComponent = *std::max_element(toModify.Components.begin(), toModify.Components.end());
        return 1.0 / maxComponent;
    }
    static double getMinParameter(const ToModify toModify){
        return 0;
    }
};

/*
 * Compute the multiple of components with a factor f.
 * The minimum parameter is the minimum of the components,
 *     such that f(min(components)) == min(components)^2.
 * The maximum parameter is the maximum of the components,
 *     such that f(max(components)) == max(components)^2.
 */
class MultipleModifier : public Modifier{
public:
    MultipleModifier(double parameter = 0) : Modifier(parameter){}

    double getResult(double component){
        return Parameter * component;
    }

    static double getMaxParameter(const ToModify toModify){
        return *std::max_element(toModify.Components.begin(), toModify.Components.end());
    }
    static double getMinParameter(const ToModify toModify){
        return *std::min_element(toModify.Components.begin(), toModify.Components.end());
    }

};

/*
 * A class to handle the mass-calculation of a ToModify objects' components
 * through a given Modifier child class, across a range of parameters.
 * The use of parallel processing highlights
 * my need to generate multiple classes of a given type, and
 * hence my (apparent) need to use templating.
 */
class ModifyManager{
protected:
    const ToModify Modify;
public:
    ModifyManager(ToModify modify) : Modify(modify){}

    template<class ModifierClass>
    std::map<double, std::vector<double>> scanModifiers(unsigned steps){
        double min = ModifierClass::getMinParameter(Modify);
        double max = ModifierClass::getMaxParameter(Modify);
        double step = (max - min)/(steps-1);

        std::map<double, std::vector<double>> result;

        #pragma omp parallel for
        for(unsigned i = 0; i < steps; ++i){
            double parameter = min + step*i;
            ModifierClass modifier(parameter);
            std::vector<double> currentResult;
            for(double m : Modify.Components){
                currentResult.push_back(modifier.getResult(m));
            }
            #pragma omp critical
            result[parameter] = currentResult;
        }
        return result;
    }

    template<class ModifierClass>
    void outputScan(unsigned steps){
        std::cout << std::endl << "-----------------" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "original: " << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::setprecision(3);
        for(double component : Modify.Components){
            std::cout << component << "\t";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl << "-----------------" << std::endl;
        std::map<double, std::vector<double>> scan = scanModifiers<ModifierClass>(steps);
        for(std::pair<double,std::vector<double>> valueSet : scan){
            std::cout << "parameter: " << valueSet.first << ": ";
            std::cout << std::endl << "-----------------" << std::endl;
            for(double component : valueSet.second){
                std::cout << component << "\t";
            }
            std::cout << std::endl << "-----------------" << std::endl;
        }
    }
};

int main(){
    ToModify m({1,2,3,4,5});
    ModifyManager manager(m);
    manager.outputScan<RatioModifier>(10);
    return 0;
}
```

I do hope this isn't too much code - I felt that a usage example was necessary. I can make a stripped down version if it helps.

In order to use this kind of thing in python, I would (in my current approach) have to pass `"RatioModifier"` or `"MultipleModifier"` to cython via an argument, which then checks the string against known values and then runs `scanModifier` with the corresponding class as a template. This is all well and good, but is problematic on the cython side when I go and add a type of modifier, or have multiple templates - it's especially bad if I have a few variations of `scanModifier` with different arguments.

The general idea is that I have a set of modifiers (in the real application, these simulate magnetic/electric fields and strain on lattices, rather than just doing basic math operations on a list of numbers) which act on values held within an object. These modifiers have a range of potential values, and it's important that the modifiers have a state (The 'parameter' used and accessed elsewhere, in uses other than scanning over ranges). The ToModify (lattice) object takes up a lot of RAM, so creating copies isn't possible.

Each modifier class has a different range of values for a given ToModify object. This is determined by the nature of the modification, not on the instance themselves, and so I can't (semantically) justify setting them as non-static methods of the objects. It seems too hacky to send an instance of the Modifier classes to the scanning method, as its state isn't meaningful.

I have considered using a factory pattern - but again, as it has no reason to hold any kind of state, it would be static - and passing a static class to a method still requires templating, which brings me back to the template translation problem in cython. I could create a factory class that accepts class name strings and chooses the correct class to use, but this seems to simply translate my issue to the C++ side.

Because I always aim to write meaningful code, I'm having a bit of a dilemma. It seems the simplest way to get around the problem is to give state to objects which do not need it, but I don't like that approach at all. What other approaches exist around this kind of problem? Should I change the way the scanning method actually works, or move it into its own kind of class? To that end, I'm stuck.

### Edit

I think it would be a good idea to provide an example of the cython side, to show how this can be such a nightmare.

Imagine I have a method such as the one above, but with two template parameters. Say, for example, one is to be a child of Modifier, and the other is a SecondaryModifier which further modifies the result (for the use of any interested: in the case of the actual program, one 'Modifier' is an EdgeManager which modifies an edge weight to simulate the effect of strain or an external magnetic field; the other can be a SimulationType - for example, a tight-binding model approach to finding energies/states, or something more involved).

And say my modifiers are `ModifierA1`, `ModifierA2`, `ModifierA3`, and my secondary modifiers are `ModifierB1`, `ModifierB2`, `ModifierB3`. And, for the sake of getting really ugly, let us have three methods which use two template arguments, `method1`, `method2`, `method3`, and give them two signatures (one taking a double, and one taking an integer). This, in a normal C++ setting, is very common and doesn't require the horrific code that follows.

```
cdef class SimulationManager:
    cdef SimulationManager_Object* pointer

    def __cinit__(self, ToModify toModify):
        self.pointer = new SimulationManager_Object(<ToModify_Object*>(toModify.pointer))

    def method1(self, str ModifierA, str ModifierB, someParameter):

        useInt = False

        if isinstance(someParameter, int):
            useInt = True
        elif not isinstance(someParameter, str):
            raise NotImplementedError("Third argument to method1 must be an int or a string")

        if ModifierA not in ["ModifierA1", "ModifierA2", "ModifierA3"]:
            raise NotImplementedError("ModifierA '%s' not handled in SimulationManager.method1" % ModifierA)
        if ModifierB not in ["ModifierB1", "ModifierB2", "ModifierB3"]:
            raise NotImplementedError("ModifierB '%s' not handled in SimulationManager.method1" % ModifierB)

        if ModifierA == "ModifierA1":
            if ModifierB == "ModifierB1":
                if useInt:
                    return self.pointer.method1[ModifierA1, ModifierB1](<int>someParameter)
                else:
                    return self.pointer.method1[ModifierA1, ModifierB1](<str>someParameter)                    
            elif ModifierB == "ModifierB2":
                if useInt:
                    return self.pointer.method1[ModifierA1, ModifierB2](<int>someParameter)
                else:
                    return self.pointer.method1[ModifierA1, ModifierB2](<str>someParameter)      
            else:
                if useInt:
                    return self.pointer.method1[ModifierA1, ModifierB3](<int>someParameter)
                else:
                    return self.pointer.method1[ModifierA1, ModifierB3](<str>someParameter)

        elif ModifierA == "ModifierA2":
            if ModifierB == "ModifierB1":
                if useInt:
                    return self.pointer.method1[ModifierA2, ModifierB1](<int>someParameter)
                else:
                    return self.pointer.method1[ModifierA2, ModifierB1](<str>someParameter)                    
            elif ModifierB == "ModifierB2":
                if useInt:
                    return self.pointer.method1[ModifierA2, ModifierB2](<int>someParameter)
                else:
                    return self.pointer.method1[ModifierA2, ModifierB2](<str>someParameter)
            else:
                if useInt:
                    return self.pointer.method1[ModifierA2, ModifierB3](<int>someParameter)
                else:
                    return self.pointer.method1[ModifierA2, ModifierB3](<str>someParameter)

        elif ModifierA == "ModifierA3":
            if ModifierB == "ModifierB1":
                if useInt:
                    return self.pointer.method1[ModifierA3, ModifierB1](<int>someParameter)
                else:
                    return self.pointer.method1[ModifierA3, ModifierB1](<str>someParameter)                    
            elif ModifierB == "ModifierB2":
                if useInt:
                    return self.pointer.method1[ModifierA3, ModifierB2](<int>someParameter)
                else:
                    return self.pointer.method1[ModifierA3, ModifierB2](<str>someParameter)
            else:
                if useInt:
                    return self.pointer.method1[ModifierA3, ModifierB3](<int>someParameter)
                else:
                    return self.pointer.method1[ModifierA3, ModifierB3](<str>someParameter)

    def method2(self, str ModifierA, str ModifierB, someParameter):

        useInt = False

        if isinstance(someParameter, int):
            useInt = True
        elif not isinstance(someParameter, str):
            raise NotImplementedError("Third argument to method2 must be an int or a string")

        if ModifierA not in ["ModifierA1", "ModifierA2", "ModifierA3"]:
            raise NotImplementedError("ModifierA '%s' not handled in SimulationManager.method2" % ModifierA)
        if ModifierB not in ["ModifierB1", "ModifierB2", "ModifierB3"]:
            raise NotImplementedError("ModifierB '%s' not handled in SimulationManager.method2" % ModifierB)

        if ModifierA == "ModifierA1":
            if ModifierB == "ModifierB1":
                if useInt:
                    return self.pointer.method2[ModifierA1, ModifierB1](<int>someParameter)
                else:
                    return self.pointer.method2[ModifierA1, ModifierB1](<str>someParameter)
            elif ModifierB == "ModifierB2":
                if useInt:
                    return self.pointer.method2[ModifierA1, ModifierB2](<int>someParameter)
                else:
                    return self.pointer.method2[ModifierA1, ModifierB2](<str>someParameter)
            else:
                if useInt:
                    return self.pointer.method2[ModifierA1, ModifierB3](<int>someParameter)
                else:
                    return self.pointer.method2[ModifierA1, ModifierB3](<str>someParameter)

        elif ModifierA == "ModifierA2":
            if ModifierB == "ModifierB1":
                if useInt:
                    return self.pointer.method2[ModifierA2, ModifierB1](<int>someParameter)
                else:
                    return self.pointer.method2[ModifierA2, ModifierB1](<str>someParameter)                    
            elif ModifierB == "ModifierB2":
                if useInt:
                    return self.pointer.method2[ModifierA2, ModifierB2](<int>someParameter)
                else:
                    return self.pointer.method2[ModifierA2, ModifierB2](<str>someParameter)
            else:
                if useInt:
                    return self.pointer.method2[ModifierA2, ModifierB3](<int>someParameter)
                else:
                    return self.pointer.method2[ModifierA2, ModifierB3](<str>someParameter)

        elif ModifierA == "ModifierA3":
            if ModifierB == "ModifierB1":
                if useInt:
                    return self.pointer.method2[ModifierA3, ModifierB1](<int>someParameter)
                else:
                    return self.pointer.method2[ModifierA3, ModifierB1](<str>someParameter)                    
            elif ModifierB == "ModifierB2":
                if useInt:
                    return self.pointer.method2[ModifierA3, ModifierB2](<int>someParameter)
                else:
                    return self.pointer.method2[ModifierA3, ModifierB2](<str>someParameter)
            else:
                if useInt:
                    return self.pointer.method2[ModifierA3, ModifierB3](<int>someParameter)
                else:
                    return self.pointer.method2[ModifierA3, ModifierB3](<str>someParameter)


    def method3(self, str ModifierA, str ModifierB, someParameter):

        useInt = False

        if isinstance(someParameter, int):
            useInt = True
        elif not isinstance(someParameter, str):
            raise NotImplementedError("Third argument to method3 must be an int or a string")

        if ModifierA not in ["ModifierA1", "ModifierA2", "ModifierA3"]:
            raise NotImplementedError("ModifierA '%s' not handled in SimulationManager.method3" % ModifierA)
        if ModifierB not in ["ModifierB1", "ModifierB2", "ModifierB3"]:
            raise NotImplementedError("ModifierB '%s' not handled in SimulationManager.method3" % ModifierB)

        if ModifierA == "ModifierA1":
            if ModifierB == "ModifierB1":
                if useInt:
                    return self.pointer.method3[ModifierA1, ModifierB1](<int>someParameter)
                else:
                    return self.pointer.method3[ModifierA1, ModifierB1](<str>someParameter)
            elif ModifierB == "ModifierB2":
                if useInt:
                    return self.pointer.method3[ModifierA1, ModifierB2](<int>someParameter)
                else:
                    return self.pointer.method3[ModifierA1, ModifierB2](<str>someParameter)
            else:
                if useInt:
                    return self.pointer.method3[ModifierA1, ModifierB3](<int>someParameter)
                else:
                    return self.pointer.method3[ModifierA1, ModifierB3](<str>someParameter)

        elif ModifierA == "ModifierA2":
            if ModifierB == "ModifierB1":
                if useInt:
                    return self.pointer.method3[ModifierA2, ModifierB1](<int>someParameter)
                else:
                    return self.pointer.method3[ModifierA2, ModifierB1](<str>someParameter)                    
            elif ModifierB == "ModifierB2":
                if useInt:
                    return self.pointer.method3[ModifierA2, ModifierB2](<int>someParameter)
                else:
                    return self.pointer.method3[ModifierA2, ModifierB2](<str>someParameter)
            else:
                if useInt:
                    return self.pointer.method3[ModifierA2, ModifierB3](<int>someParameter)
                else:
                    return self.pointer.method3[ModifierA2, ModifierB3](<str>someParameter)

        elif ModifierA == "ModifierA3":
            if ModifierB == "ModifierB1":
                if useInt:
                    return self.pointer.method3[ModifierA3, ModifierB1](<int>someParameter)
                else:
                    return self.pointer.method3[ModifierA3, ModifierB1](<str>someParameter)                    
            elif ModifierB == "ModifierB2":
                if useInt:
                    return self.pointer.method3[ModifierA3, ModifierB2](<int>someParameter)
                else:
                    return self.pointer.method3[ModifierA3, ModifierB2](<str>someParameter)
            else:
                if useInt:
                    return self.pointer.method3[ModifierA3, ModifierB3](<int>someParameter)
                else:
                    return self.pointer.method3[ModifierA3, ModifierB3](<str>someParameter)
```

This amount of code is not only ridiculous for the functionality, but it means that I now need to edit the .h files, the .cpp files, the .pxd files AND the .pyx file *just to add one new type of modifier*. Considering we programmers have an in-built obsession with efficiency, this kind of process just isn't acceptable to me.

Again, I acknowledge that this is a kind-of necessary process with cython (although I can think of many ways this process can be improved upon. Perhaps when I have more free time I'll join the community effort). What I'm asking is purely on the C++ side (unless there IS a workaround in cython that myself and Google are unaware of).

One thing I hadn't previously considered was a factory whose state indicates the type of objects to be created, and pass this along. This seems slightly wasteful, though, and again is just sweeping the problem under the rug. If anything, I'm really asking for ideas (or design patterns), and I don't mind how crazy or incomplete they are; I just want to get some creativity flowing.

Comment: Why not select the modifier at run time by means of objects and virtual functions?

Comment: Care to elaborate? Im creating N of these mods within the scanning method. Passing an object seems pointless, as its state is not read by the method. I could pass a factory, but again the state would be unused and it would thus be static and we return to the same problem of static inheritance. I could make a new class, which is a general factory for the modifier, and accepts a parameter (the modifier to create). This still requires some kind of checking mechanism to tell it what to create. I'm not looking for a way around (that part is easy enough). I'm looking to have a meaningful structure.

Comment: (not the person who's comment you're replying to but:) I'd create a class `ModifierMaker` which has a function `Modifier createModifer(int)`. The state of `ModifierMaker` is either some variable dictating the type of what to return, or you use inheritance and make the function virtual (and thus the state is contained in the vtable). You pass your `ModifierMaker`(s) to `scanModifiers` (now not templated) and that's it.

Comment: Looking at the very end of your edited post - this is basically what you suggest. I'd argue this isn't really wasteful. In C++ you solve this by knowing what Modifiers you want at compile time. However if you're ever in the position where you don't know - e.g. you want to change based on user input, you have to compile every combination and pick one at runtime, like in Python. You've therefore got to store the state and storing it in the factory makes as much sense as anything.

Comment: One final thought (about a different approach) - you might be able to build a C++ version of `SimulationManager.method1` using variadic templates, which would involve a lot less repetitious `if` statements. I'm happy to have a go at building an outline version of this if wanted, but I don't really think it's the right solution...

Comment: Are you required to use Cython? SWIG has C++ template support (http://swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Python_nn26) and can do most of the wrapping automatically.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.

Dietrich: SWIG is certainly interesting. The fact that it allows template-specific versions of methods to be referenced in a variable-like manner is nice. I will have a ponder on that and get back to you. Cython certainly seemed more appealing at the start of the project.

DavidW: I think, if I stay with Cython, that a factory is going to have to do. It's a shame that Cython approaches this kind of problem in the way it does. I think I can justify the use of factory to myself with the following: Why _should_ the modifier class know its own limits for a system?

Comment: We have had some success avoiding this problem by using a variant data type to translate between Python and C++. Variants are much quicker to convert back and forth than strings. The conversion routines have to be written only once, and the data can then be used by all relevant functions.

Comment: @EvertW: That seems rather interesting - would you mind posting an example (it does not have to be based on this existing code, I don't want to take your time!) as an answer? Thanks.

Comment: @Dietrich: I would like to thank you for your suggestion for using SWIG. It has its advantages and disadvantages, but I tried it with my project over the weekend to great success. A couple of things to work out, but I think I will stick with it. Sure beats manually wrapping everything (though Ive stuck with the factory method, as it "feels" better)

Answer (score 3):

Okay, so I've been playing around with the factory idea. I'm still not convinced that it's "meaningful", but perhaps my obsession with "justifiable" state just isn't worth the hassle in this case.

To that end, I propose the following. A generalised factory class that returns a generalised modifier, with a child templated factory that handles some of the common (but class-specific) methods, and specific child factories that override the parameters. This does mean relying on pointers (to return abstract class pointers from the generalised factory), but I was using those in my original codebase (not just for the sake of it, honest).

I do not believe this is the best approach (and will not "accept" it as an answer). However, it means that I can avoid nested if statements. I thought I would post it for comments. Some of your advice in the comments has been exceptional, and I would like to thank you all for it.

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <omp.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

/*
 * Just a class containing some components to run through
 * a Modifier (see below)
 */
class ToModify{
public:
    std::vector<double> Components;
    ToModify(std::vector<double> components) : Components(components){}
};

/*
 * An abstract class which handles the modification of ToModify
 * components in an arbitrary way. They each have a range of valid
 * parameters.
 * These parameters have a minimum and maximum value, which is
 * to be determined by the _factory_.
 */
class Modifier{
protected:
    double Parameter;
public:
    Modifier(double parameter = 0) : Parameter(parameter){}
    void setParameter(double parameter){
        Parameter = parameter;
    }
    double getParameter(){
        return Parameter;
    }
    virtual double getResult(double component) = 0;
};

/*
 * A generalised modifier factory, acting as the parent class
 * for the specialised ChildModifierFactories below. This will
 * be the type that the scanning method accepts as an argument.
 */
class GeneralModifierFactory{
public:
    virtual Modifier* get(double parameter) = 0;
    virtual double getMinParameter(ToModify const toModify) = 0;
    virtual double getMaxParameter(ToModify const toModify) = 0;
};

/*
 * This takes the type of modifier as a template argument. It
 * is designed to be a parent to the ModifierFactories that
 * follow. Other common methods that involve the modifier
 * can be placed here to save code.
 */
template<class ChildModifier>
class ChildModifierFactory : public GeneralModifierFactory{
public:
    ChildModifier* get(double parameter){
        return new ChildModifier(parameter);
    }
    virtual double getMinParameter(ToModify const toModify) = 0;
    virtual double getMaxParameter(ToModify const toModify) = 0;
};

/*
 * Compute component ratios with a pre-factor.
 * The minimum is zero, such that getResult(component) == 0 for all components.
 * The maximum is such that getResult(component) <= 1 for all components.
 */
class RatioModifier : public Modifier{
public:
    RatioModifier(double parameter = 0) : Modifier(parameter){}
    double getResult(double component){
        return Parameter * component;
    }
};

/*
 * This class handles the ranges of parameters which are valid in
 * the RatioModifier. The parent class handles the constructions.
 */
class RatioModifierFactory : public ChildModifierFactory<RatioModifier>{
public:

    double getMaxParameter(ToModify const toModify){
        double maxComponent = *std::max_element(toModify.Components.begin(), toModify.Components.end());
        return 1.0 / maxComponent;
    }

    double getMinParameter(ToModify const toModify){
        return 0;
    }
};

/*
 * Compute the multiple of components with a factor f.
 * The minimum parameter is the minimum of the components,
 *     such that f(min(components)) == min(components)^2.
 * The maximum parameter is the maximum of the components,
 *     such that f(max(components)) == max(components)^2.
 */
class MultipleModifier : public Modifier{
public:
    MultipleModifier(double parameter = 0) : Modifier(parameter){}
    double getResult(double component){
        return Parameter * component;
    }
};

/*
 * This class handles the ranges of parameters which are valid in
 * the MultipleModifier. The parent class handles the constructions.
 */
class MultipleModifierFactory : public ChildModifierFactory<MultipleModifier>{
public:
    double getMaxParameter(ToModify const toModify){
        return *std::max_element(toModify.Components.begin(), toModify.Components.end());
    }
    double getMinParameter(ToModify const toModify){
        return *std::min_element(toModify.Components.begin(), toModify.Components.end());
    }
};

/*
 * A class to handle the mass-calculation of a ToModify objects' components
 * through a given Modifier child class, across a range of parameters.
 */
class ModifyManager{
protected:
    ToModify const Modify;
public:
    ModifyManager(ToModify modify) : Modify(modify){}

    std::map<double, std::vector<double>> scanModifiers(GeneralModifierFactory& factory, unsigned steps){
        double min = factory.getMinParameter(Modify);
        double max = factory.getMaxParameter(Modify);
        double step = (max - min)/(steps-1);

        std::map<double, std::vector<double>> result;

        #pragma omp parallel for
        for(unsigned i = 0; i < steps; ++i){
            double parameter = min + step*i;
            Modifier* modifier = factory.get(parameter);
            std::vector<double> currentResult;
            for(double m : Modify.Components){
                currentResult.push_back(modifier->getResult(m));
            }
            delete modifier;
            #pragma omp critical
            result[parameter] = currentResult;
        }
        return result;
    }

    void outputScan(GeneralModifierFactory& factory, unsigned steps){
        std::cout << std::endl << "-----------------" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "original: " << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::setprecision(3);
        for(double component : Modify.Components){
            std::cout << component << "\t";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl << "-----------------" << std::endl;
        std::map<double, std::vector<double>> scan = scanModifiers(factory, steps);
        for(std::pair<double,std::vector<double>> valueSet : scan){
            std::cout << "parameter: " << valueSet.first << ": ";
            std::cout << std::endl << "-----------------" << std::endl;
            for(double component : valueSet.second){
                std::cout << component << "\t";
            }
            std::cout << std::endl << "-----------------" << std::endl;
        }
    }
};

int main(){
    ToModify m({1,2,3,4,5});
    ModifyManager manager(m);
    RatioModifierFactory ratio;
    MultipleModifierFactory multiple;
    manager.outputScan(ratio, 10);
    std::cout << " --------------- " << std::endl;
    manager.outputScan(multiple, 10);
    return 0;
}
```

Now I can either pass a wrapped factory class, or a string which can be converted to such a class (via a helper function) for each such parameter. Not completely ideal because the factory has a state - it does not need to, unless it has a ToModify object as a member (which seems rather pointless). But, alas, it works.